# How do I build a Phonegap application for Android 2.3?

Tags: android, cordova, build, phonegap-build

I need to target this older platform in a Phonegap application.

So far I've tried:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="8" />
```

in my `config.xml`, but the build seems to fail with:

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library /home/ldc/myapp/platforms/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/android/CordovaLib/unspecified/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
```

I've also tried setting:

```
<engine name="android" spec="~2.3.0" />
```

but I keep on getting:

```
Error: No compatible version found: cordova-android@'>=2.3.0 <2.4.0'
Valid install targets:
["3.5.0","3.5.1","3.6.0","3.6.1","3.6.3","3.6.4","3.7.0","3.7.1","4.0.0","4.0.1","3.7.2","4.0.2","4.1.0","4.1.1","5.0.0"]
```

Any hints?

Comment: Do you need Phonegap(-Build)? Otherwise you can use cordova and install an old version.

Answer (score 1):

@idc,
If you are using *Phonegap Build*, the cloud-based build service by Phonegap (Adobe), then the lowest version you can build is the lowest version supported by Google Android - in this case SDK 14.

I tried to find the documentation for this, for you, but in a recent change to *Phonegap Build* documentation, there was an error. I will file a bug report in just a bit.

The best I could do is find the [Cordova documentation for Android](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/guide/platforms/android/index.html). It states:

> Cordova supports Android 4.0.x (starting with Android API level 14) and higher. As a general rule, Android versions become unsupported by Cordova as they dip below 5% on Google's [distribution dashboard](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html). Android versions earlier than API level 10, and the 3.x versions (Honeycomb, API levels 11-13) fall significantly below that 5% threshold.

To be clear, API level 10 (Gingerbread) was available until about July, but is  no loner available. If you require an earlier API Level, then I would use the *Phonegap CLI* as @Joerg is suggesting.

- Wikipedia - [Android Version History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history)

**FACT** Google's number are false and misleading. Those number reflect devices that register on a weekly basis with "Google Play". This is stated this at the bottom of the chart, but the number are read incorrectly, interpreted incorrectly, and published incorrectly. Google does NOTHING to correct the misinterpretation. Those numbers are NOT reflective of the actual number of device (on a per version basis) in the field. - Best of Luck.

Answer (score 0):

The engine tag doesn't select the android SDK version, it select the cordova android version

android 2.3 support was removed on cordova android 4.1.0, so you can set any previous version using the engine tag

Example tag with the latest cordova android version that supported android 2.3

```
<engine name="android" spec="~4.0.2" />
```

and android 2.3 uses SDK 10, not 8

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" />
```